# Dealing with a wrapped IntPtr Object

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, opencv, emgucv

I'm translating some OpenCV code from C++ to C# wrapped by EmguCV. One thing continuously bothers me is that in Opencv, a lot of stuff are pointers say `IplImage*`, `CvCapture*`, etc and when I translate them into C#, they all become `IntPtrs` like `IntPtr Capture=CvInvoke.CvCreateCameraCapture(0)` In this particular question, I'm having problem accessing the data of a matrix in form of `IntPtr`

The original Code looks like:

```
CvMat* ObjectPoints = CvCreateMat(/*some parameters*/);//initialize the matrix header
float* TempPoints = new float[/*size of the array of the TempPoints*/];
//assign some values to TempPoints
*ObjectPoints = cvMat(rows, cols, type, TempPoints)//assign the changed TempPoints as the data of the ObjectPoint matrix. other irrelevant parameters are omitted.
```

When I rewrite the part above in C#, it looks like

```
IntPtr ObjectPoints = CvInvoke.CvCreateMat(/*some parameters*/);
float* TempPoints = new float[/*size of the array of the tempPoints*/];
//assign some value to TempPoints
//Then what? ObjectPoints is a pointer and EmguCV does not have a CvMat() method. So how can I achieve the effect as in the original code?
```

And if I could expand a little beyond this question, in other occasions like I have `IntPtr Frame = CvInoke.CvQueryImage(Capture);` and another function requires an `Image<RGB, Byte>`, how can I convert an IntPtr to an Image? I know the reverse one is simple, just use MyImage.Ptr. But how to convert an IntPtr to an Image?

Comment: You need to write C++/CLI wrapper.

Comment: This just leads me to believe that EmguCV isn't a very good wrapper.

Comment: It is possible to marshal the class to C#, but it's a little bit ugly. You will be able to write this in C#: `CvMat* ObjectPoints = CvCreateMat(...`. You can also access class members in C# with the `->` operator: `ObjectPoints->...`. However, some questions: the first line in your code has `ObjectPointS` and the last line has `ObjectPoint`. Also, the last line does not indicate any reference to the `CvMat` object returned by `CvCreateMat`. And: Do you need to access any class members of `CvMat`? Maybe I can help you if you provide more concise information.

Comment: @dialer I don't know how to say that. I have a `TempPoint` array and I want that array to be the data of the `ObjectPoints`. Because EmguCV does not have a `CvMat()` method and I can not do something like `ObjectPoints->data=TempPoint`. I did some research and I come up with `Matrix<float> TempMat = new Matrix<float>(TempPoints); ObjectPoints=CvInvoke.cvInitMatHeader(ObjectPoints,..., TempMat.Ptr, ...)` Do you think it's the right way to achieve my goal or do you have any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: @YankeeWhiskey The function `cvMat` is a fast inline substitution for `cvInitMatHeader`. `cvInitMatHeader` is available in EmguCV. As I see it, the fact that everything is an `IntPtr` is not your problem after all.